# Tensorflow: access shape of placeholder after NN layer in code

Tags: tensorflow

So, here is what I want to do:

Right now, I have `padding = 'SAME'` for all of my neural net layers.  I would like to make my code more generic, so I can build my nets with arbitrary paddings, and I don't want to have to calculate how big the output tensors of the layers of my net are.  I would like to just access the dimension at initialization/run time, the way the `tf.nn` functions apparently do internally, so I can initialize my weight and bias tensors in the correct dimension...

So,

How do I access the "shape" function/object of the output placeholder of a convolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of shapes -- `tensor.get_shape()` which gives static shape computed by Python wrappers during Graph construction (whenever possible), and `tf.shape(tensor)` which is an op that can be executed during runtime to get shape of the tensor (always possible). Both of these work for convolutions.

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.ones((1, 3, 3, 1)))
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones((3, 3, 1, 1)))
c = tf.nn_ops.conv2d(a, b, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")
sess = create_session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print c.get_shape()
print sess.run(tf.shape(c))
```

This gives

```
(1, 1, 1, 1)
[1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Ok, I think this will get me close, but I am not sure, because I am trying to use the shape during construction of the graph (i.e, before initialization).  I will include a code example of what I am trying to do when I get back.